# Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'Observable<GridDataResult> --aot (See edit)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm trying to do data binding using Kendo Grid. Everything works except when building the app in production mode (--aot)

Here is where the error is coming from:

```js
//This is a service




Here are reference

export abstract class MainService extends BehaviorSubject<GridDataResult> {
  public loading: boolean;
  public pageSize: number = 10;

  products: Product[] = [];

  
  protected fetch(state: any): Observable<GridDataResult> {
    this.loading = true;
   // Make API call and map values
   
  }
}


// This is in my component

public view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
```

```html
<kendo-grid id="productsGrid" [data]="view | async" [loading]="view.loading" [pageSize]="state.take" [skip]="state.skip"
  [sort]="state.sort" [sortable]="true" [pageable]="true" [scrollable]="'none'" (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
  (remove)="removeHandler($event)">
  <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Name" width="130"></kendo-grid-column>

</kendo-grid>
```

The error comes up only when compiling though: 
    Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'Observable'

I am ensuring property loading is `public`. But it is not helping.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Edit: Basically what the error is saying is that there is no view.loading property because view is an Observable and there's no loading property in an observable.

Comment: Please provide the API call code

Comment: Here is the reference:       https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/

Comment: I meant, your code to call the api.

Comment: It's in the same link (View source) Here's the code: `protected fetch(tableName: string, state: any): Observable<GridDataResult> {
        const queryStr = `${toODataString(state)}&$count=true`;
        this.loading = true;

        return this.http
            .get(`${this.BASE_URL}${tableName}?${queryStr}`)
            .pipe(
                map(response => (<GridDataResult>{
                    data: response['value'],
                    total: parseInt(response['@odata.count'], 10)
                })),
                tap(() => this.loading = false)
            );
    }`

Comment: Here's the same code in StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxjkau

Comment: I have edited my question to say that the AOT compiler is erroring because theres no view.loading property. I believe this is not related to API calls

Comment: In your case, `<kendo-grid  [loading]="view.loading" ... >` should be `<kendo-grid  [loading]="loading" ... >`

Comment: I'll give it a go.. I'll report back in a sec. Edit: Nope, it doesn't work unfortunately. I am actually confused why ng serve works fine, stackblitz works fine, but aot compilation doesnt work :(

Comment: This behavior will change in the near future, dev will be the same as prod.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so I asked Telerik and they told me to use array notation instead of dot: `[loading]="view['loading']"`.  This builds fine for me and still shows the loading icon correctly.

Comment: brilliant.. trying the examples on their site and got this issue - thanks for the answer, saved me !!